# how to reload the activity without refreshing?

Tags: android

i switch to next screen  and then comes back to the original and wants to pick up where i  left off , save and restore data.In Activity 1:i have more than 10 buttons i can select and unselect button,if go to next screen and if i come back it should not reload,it should show me where i leftoff,

```
    up1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.adultup1);
    up1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (upt1 == 0) {
                up1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.adultup1);
                upt1 = 1;
            } else {
                up1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.adultup1_pressed);
                upt1 = 0;
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at image (and read text too) here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html

If you need to not reload state, you should think about what are you doing in each activity state.

If you do:

> Activity1 -> startActivity(Activity2) -> Activity2 -> Activity2.onBackPressed -> Activity1

than, there is no reloading. On return from second to first you got called `onResume`

but If you do:

> Activity1 -> startActivity(Activity2) -> Activity2 -> startActivity(Activity1) -> Activity1

then you need to save your state in some external class (static class member) and load Activity1 state from it in `onCreate` state.
The same would be (as you can see from image), when app proccess is killed, and user returns to interrupted activity.

If you simply return to Activity1 using `finish()` on Activity2, there will be no call to `onCreate`, just `onResume`

[image]

---

Store Button state

```
public static int _state = -1;

onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    if(_state == -1){
        _state = 0;
        // this is first time we're using "_state" variable, so do init
    } else {
        // this is second or later, so just load state variable and setup UI
    }
}
```

Comment: sample code of what? I think, you need to realize how to handle activity lifecycle in each exact activity case

Comment: Activity1 -> startActivity(Activity2) -> Activity2 -> Activity2.onBackPressed -> Activity1.here how can i store the state  in static class

Comment: Read again, in this case, state is saved and not overwritten by `onCreate`, so you don't need to store it in class.

Comment: ok. Activity 2:intent = new Intent(seek.this,MainScreen.class);startActivity(intent); here i am getting fresh one .

Comment: @user828948 tried to create some example code, it's usable for storing one state, you will have to modify it to fit your needs

Comment: i updated my code above,can u help me in if and else what i have to do?

Comment: @user828948 create new question, and point from it to this question (as releated to my previous question, or so). Don't use edit to change question topic

Comment: in my above code i have more than ten buttons like up1 and next button

Comment: when i click next and if i come back it should show all where i left off

Comment: @user828948 so create `public static int[] buttons` and store their values inside. Or `public static ArrayList<Integer> buttons`, if you need simplier solution

Comment: how to store values in arraylist

Comment: @user828948 lay down another question, this is not in the scope of current question

Comment: i have buttons like up1,up2.....up16,similarly dwn1,dwn2,...dwn16.if it is selected its value will be one

Comment: @user828948 create new question, i won't answer you here !

Comment: from this how can i send selected teeth to arraylist